# Tools required to learn ARM on linux x86 platform

Tags: linux, arm, assembly

I've a x86, linux box. while reading some assorted information on ARM, i got curious and now I'm thinking of spending some time learning this architecture. My goal as of now is to be able to write trivial assembly programs for ARM, use some assembler to generate the target code for ARM and be able to run that program on an emulated ARM machine. To start with I've downloaded ARM architecture reference manual. According to the information [here](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1456.htm) , Keil is not supported on Linux, hence
please help me with the tools(assembler, emulator) that I'd need.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, you need two things - a toolchain and an emulator.

The toolchain consists of all that you need to build applications for the ARM architecture and to run it on the target (in your case, an emulator). A good place to start would be [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) or [ELDK](http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/ELDK). These will provide you with a complete cross-Linux solution. If you want to only be able to compile, without working with a Linux installation (and the accompanying rootfs), you can use only a cross-compiler. One free is [CodeSourcery](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm), but there are some others as well (most based on GCC).

The emulator is the place you will run the code, that will behave like an ARM CPU. A good place to start is [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page).

Cross-projects have a rather steep learning curve, and require lots of searching online to get things done. Rarely are there detailed step-by-step guides for the entire process, but there are many guides for various parts of the work.

Comment: Thanks Eli, I downloaded buildroot and did the basic steps mentioned under the README section. After the successful completion of make, the toolchain for the target macine(arm) in my case was found under ~/buildroot-<version>/output/host/usr/bin . Now as you've mentioned i'll try to run simple arm machine code on the emulated processor by QEMU. Thanks again for your help, and please let me know if i've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

A simple "Hello world" in ARM64 on Ubuntu x86_64

`sudo apt install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
F='test'
cat <<EOT > $F.s
  .text
  .globl main
  main:
    mov x8, #64
    mov x0, #1
    adr x1, msg
    mov x2, 13
    svc #0
    ret

  msg:
  .ascii "hello world\n"
EOT

aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -static -c $F.s
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -static -o $F $F.o
./$F
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

There are cross compilers of GCC available for ARM targets; Code Sourcery is a fairly common one if you want one pre-built.

As to an emulation environment, qemu does a good job of emulating the ARM. Google's Android emulator is based on eqmu (and their "NDK" is another source of a pre-built ARM cross compiler).